# python3 HitBTC Restfull API

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am making a program to order from HitBTC 's Restfull API with Python 3.
I think that it is correctly implemented, but an error is returned.
The error is 403 Wrong signature.
The signature definition of the document is lower-case hex representation of hmac-sha 512 of concatenated uri and postData.
HitBTC Document -> https://hitbtc.com/api#tradingrestful
I'd like you to tell me the mistake in the program below.

```
API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
SECRET_KEY = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'
BASE_URL = 'http://demo-api.hitbtc.com'

nonce = str(int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple()) * 1000 + datetime.datetime.now().microsecond / 1000))
req = {
    'clientOrderId': "".join(random.choice(string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase)for _ in range(30)),
    'symbol': 'BTCUSD',
    'side': 'buy',
    'price': '3',
    'quantity': '100',
    'type': 'limit'
}
postdata = urllib.parse.urlencode(req)
url_path = '/api/1/trading/new_order?apikey=' + API_KEY + '&nonce=' + nonce
signature = hmac.new(SECRET_KEY.encode(), (url_path + postdata).encode(), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
reuslt = requests.post(BASE_URL + url_path, params=postdata, headers={'X-Signature': signature})

print(reuslt.json())
```

Comment: You are hashing the urlquoted data and sending JSON. This way the hash can't match.

Comment: I watched comments. Thank you very much. I fixed it but it did not go well.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you rebuilt the wheel ? Better to use the [official hitbtc python code client](https://github.com/hitbtc-com/hitbtc-api/blob/master/example_rest.py)  from Github.

Once you have [create an account on Hitbtc](https://hitbtc.com/?ref_id=59aeac9f76e23), and [create API key](https://hitbtc.com/settings/api-keys), and add the Access Right. You can do the job with the [python client api](https://github.com/hitbtc-com/hitbtc-api/blob/master/example_rest.py).

Please consider also that **API V1 is outdated**, and it is better to **switch to API V2**.

You may finaly refer to the [official Hitbtc API documentation](https://api.hitbtc.com/#cancelorder).

Regards